# Singular express refer to nonexisting object?

Tags: html, csv, optimization

I am using below code for reporting purpose, everything was fine but all of sudden this code started giving error saying Singular expression refer to nonexisting object

I also break the whole code bit by bit & able to trace the problem but confused what to use in there & why its giving that error statement.

if I remove following part I am able to get the results & relevance works perfectly fine but that will break the formatting which required to csv output.

**(html it) of concatenations of**

```
<?relevance
(html it) of concatenations of ( "%22" &
  name of computer of it & "%22|%22" &
name of issuer of action of it & "%22|%22" &
name of action of it & "%22|%22" &
status of it as string & "%22|%22" &
state of action of it & "%22%0d%0a"
)
of results of bes actions whose (name of it starts with "Config_item")
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, actually the output which this code is generating against each from was not available for some property which cause the problem.

after I made the below changes into it with else condition it solve the problem.

```
(html it) of concatenations of ( "%22" &
  (name of computer of it | "None") & "%22|%22" &
name of issuer of action of it & "%22|%22" &
name of action of it & "%22|%22" &
status of it as string & "%22|%22" &
state of action of it & "%22%0d%0a"
)
```

This line actually helped in solving this - (name of computer of it | "None")